# Geocoding mysql addresses

Tags: geocode

I want to geocode mysql addresses to get latitude and longitude and save them into mysql table. I got this code from a friend some time ago, so somenthing could be deprecated.

I have this scripts:

index.php

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W§C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Geocodification</title>title>

<?php
require("config.php");

$output = '';
$markerListLat = array();
$markerListLng = array();

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', BBDD_USER, BBDD_PASSWD);
if (!connection) { die("Error en la connecion a la BBDD: " . mysql_error()); }

$db_selected = mysql_selected_db(BBDD_NAME, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) { die("Error en el accesso al BBDD: " . mysql_error()); }    

$query = 'SELECT * FROM tplace WHERE 1 ORDER BY id ASC';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!result) { die("Error en la consulta a la BBDD: " . mysql_error()); }   

$delay = 0;
$base_url = "http://".MAPS_HOST."/maps/geo?output=csv&key=".KEY;

$output = '<dl>';   
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $geocode_pending = true;

    while ($geocode_pending)
    {
        $id = $row["id"];
        $address = utf8_decode($row['direccion']).', '.utf8_decode($row['codigo_postal']);

        $request_url = $base_url."&q=".urlencode($address);
        $csv = file_get_contents($request_url) or die("url not loading");

        $csvLine = explode(",", $csv);
        $status = $csvLine[0];
        $lat = $csvLine[2];
        $lng = $csvLine[3];

        array_push($markerListLat, $lat);
        array_push($markerListLng, $lng);

        if (strcmp($status, STATUS_OK) == 0)
        {
            // EXITO EN LA GEOCODIFICATION
            $geocode_pending = false;

            //Actualizamos los valores de la BBDD
            $query = sprintf("UPDATE tplace = " .
                            " SET latitud = '§s', longitud = '§s' " .
                            " WHERE id = §s LIMIZ 1;",
            mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
            mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
            mysql_real_escape_string($id));

            $update_result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$update_result)
            {
                die ("SQL Query erronea: " . mysql_error());
            }   
            else
            {
                $output .= '<dt>EXITO > geocodificando la siguiente direccion: '.$address.'</dt>';
                $output .= '<dd>(Lat, Lng) > ('.$lat.', '.$lng.')</dd>';
            }   

            usleep($delay);
        }
    }
    $output .= '</dl>';

?>
</head>

<body onload="initialize();">
    <h1>Geodification de Base de Datos</h1>h1>
    <p><?php echo $output; ?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

config.php

```html
<?php
    define('BBDD_USER', 'root');
    define('BBDD_PASSWD', '');
    define('BBDD_NAME', 'geocoding_demo');

    define('MAPS_HOST', 'maps.google_demo');
    define('KEY', 'MY KEY');
    define('STATUS_OK', '200');
    define('STATUS_KO_TIME', '620');
    define('DELAY_TIME', 1000000);

    define('SPAIN_LAT', 40.396764);
    define('SPAIN_LNG', -3.713379);
    define('SPAIN_ZOOM', 6);
?>
```

tplace.sql

```html
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

--
-- Database: `geocoding_demo`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `tplace`
--

CREATE TABLE `tplace` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `localidad` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `codigo_postal` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pais` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `latitud` float(10,6) NOT NULL,
  `longitud` float(10,6) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `tplace`
--

INSERT INTO `tplace` (`id`, `nombre`, `direccion`, `localidad`, `codigo_postal`, `pais`, `latitud`, `longitud`) VALUES
(1, '', '68 Rue Jean Jaurès, 'Bauvin', '59221', 'Frankreich', 0.000000, 0.000000),
(2, '', 'via castello, 19', 'Bargni', '61030', 'Italien', 0.000000, 0.000000),

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `tplace`
--
ALTER TABLE `tplace`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for dumped tables
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT for table `tplace`
--
ALTER TABLE `tplace`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=4;
COMMIT;
```

I am getting blank page on browser and this error: GET HTTP/1.0 500 Internal Server Error.

Does someone could please help me?
Thanks,

Nicola

Comment: What does your server's error log tell you about it? What happens if you debug the code, either through `var_dump` or a proper debugger?

Comment: After cleaning up the spacing in your code a little, it appears that you are not closing one of your `while` loops.